# Fetching correct node using xpath in Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Visit this [link](http://www.myntra.com/jackets/vero-moda/vero-moda-black-jacket/1568991/buy)

I want to get the `product material & care` details.

```
Shell: 70% polyester, 30% wool
Lining: 100% polyester
Dry-clean.
```

I have tried below mentioned code, but it does not work for me.

```
self.browser.find_element_by_xpath("//h6[@class='pdp-product-description-title']/p").text
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<p>` tag is a sibling, not a child element. Use `following-sibling::p`

```
self.browser.find_element_by_xpath("//h6[@class='pdp-product-description-title']/following-sibling::p").text
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this way.

**Explanation of xpath:-** Start `xpath` with `<h6>` tag along with `text` method and then move ahead with `<p>` tag using `following` keyword.

```
self.browser.find_element_by_xpath("//h6[contains(text(), 'Material & Care')]/following::p[@class='pdp-product-description-content']").text
```

> OR

Use Indexing with `<p>` tag.

```
self.browser.find_element_by_xpath("//h6[contains(text(), 'Material & Care')]/following::p[1]").text
```

Comment: Does my explanation of code helped you? If it does then please mark this answer as `Accepted` if it's resolved your issue.